# Finding the linear span of a polynomial with a condition

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to find the linear span of the following set:

$M = \{p(x)∈ \mathbb R_4 [x] : p(x)=p(x-1),  x∈\mathbb R\} $

I've tried taking a vector from $M$ and applying the condition on it. Like that:

Let:
$p(x) ∈ M$

$p(x) = p(x-1)$

$a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 = a + b(x-1) + c(x-1)^2 + d(x-1)^3 $

$b(1) + c(2x-1) + d(3x^2 -3x +1) = 0$

$(b-c+d) + (2c-3d)x + (3d)x^2 = 0$

Now, if I open an equation system based on the variables of the polynomial, I get that b, c and d are equal to 0.
What does that mean in terms of the linear span?
Am I trying to find it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a polynomial satisfies $p(x)=p(x-1), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider $q(x)= p(x)-p(0)$, then $0$ is a root of $q$, and every integer is a root of $q$.

Hence $q$ is the $0$ function and we conclude that $p$ is a constant function.

In general, we have shown that a periodic polynomial is a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

Equate  the coefficients to $0$ and you will get $b=c=d=0$. Since $a$ is arbitrary the span is simply the set of all constant polynomials.

Comment: I understand, so my line of thinking is correct, then?
I found that b, c and d are all equal to 0.
Therefore, the span for the group would be:

$M = Sp\{1,0, 0, 0\}$

Comment: @EatayMizrachi Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let V = $\{P(x) \in \mathbb{R}_4[x]: P(x) = P(x-1) \}$, what you showed means that $V \subset \text{Span}\{ 1 \}$, (where in this case 1 is the polynomial, not the scalar). On the other hand, any constant polynomial is in V. Hence $V = \text{Span}\{ 1 \}$, the subspace of constant polynomials.